# VLC using :input-slave parameter in JS api

Tags: javascript, vlc

I'm trying with no luck the following code to play two files (video + audio) at the same time with the VLC JS api using the :input-slave option.

Separately, they play just fine.

Do anyone have an idea?

Thankyou!

```
function doGo(){

    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");

    var options = [":rtsp-tcp",":input-slave=file://place/audio.WAV"];

      var itemId = vlc.playlist.add("file://place/video.AVI","",options);
      options = [];
       vlc.playlist.playItem(itemId);
    }
}
```